# Adding strings to 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to write a program that looks for the first empty space in a 2D array and  adds a custom string to that space. I have tried some things that i found on the internet but none seem to work or match my specific scenario. This is it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int tags[10] = {1,2,3,4,5};
char owners[10][10] = {"per1", "per2", "per3", "per4", "per5"};
int tagAdd;
char ownerAdd;
int i;
int addBool;
int j;
int len;

int main()
{
   printf("Enter the tag ID you want to add: ");
   scanf("%d", &tagAdd);
   printf("Enter the tag owners name: ");
   scanf("%d", &ownerAdd);
   len = strlen(ownerAdd);

   while (i<10)
   {
       if (tags[i] == 0)
       {
           tags[i] = tagAdd;
           owners[i][len] = ownerAdd; //This is the part I can't figure out
           addBool = 1;
       }
       if (addBool == 1)
       {
           break;
       }
       i++;
   }

   i = 0;
   addBool = 0;
   len = 0;

   while (i<10)
   {
       printf("tag[%d]", tags[i]);
       len = strlen(owners[i]);
       printf(" is owned by ");
       while (j < len)
           {
               printf("%c", owners[i][j]);
               j++;
           }
       printf("\n\r");
       i++;
       j = 0;
   }

}
```

Comment: Does this help; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774758/how-to-add-a-string-to-a-2d-array-in-c

Comment: "first empty space in a 2D" is a bit unclear.  A 2D array can not have any _empty_ space.  In this case, the 2D `char owners[10][10]` consists of 10*10 or 100 elements (`char`).  Looks like this is more about `char owners[10][10]` as 10 _strings_ and code is looking for the first _string_ that begins with a _null character_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this:

```
char ownerAdd;

scanf("%d", &ownerAdd);
len = strlen(ownerAdd);
```

You are passing the incorrect types. `ownerAdd` is a single `char`, `scanf`
expects with `%d` a pointer to `int`, you are passing a pointer to `char` and if
`scanf` converts the value, it will overflow. And `strlen` expects a `char*`
which points to a valid string (0-terminated). You are doing all this wrong.

This would be correct:

```
char ownerAdd[100];
scanf("%99s", ownerAdd);
len = strlen(ownerAdd);
```

And for replacing a value:

```
owners[i][len] = ownerAdd; //This is the part I can't figure out
```

is also wrong, because `owners[i]` is a `char[10]`, you have to do:

```
strncpy(owners[i], ownerAdd, sizeof owners[i]);
owners[i][sizeof(owners[i]) - 1] = 0;
```

to copy the string.

The next error is that you don't initialize `i` and do (the first loop)

```
while (i<10)
{
    ...
}
```

this is going to fail. Same thing with `j`, it is uninitialized.

Comment: There defenitely were alot of flaws in my code, thanks alot for helping me out here!